# Creating non-random matched pairs

Tags: r, statistics, methodology

I am looking for an R package that would allow me to match match each subject in a treatment group to a subject in the general population that has similar characteristics (age, gender, etc).

Comment: please create a reproducible example with data so we can better help

Comment: It's not really hard to find it using google. Just try, (a clue: Package Matching)

Comment: The solutions I found using Google either involve random matching or complex algorithms (e.g. distance estimation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the MatchIt package for doing this type of thing. You may receive advice to use propensity score matching, but there are limitations to that widely used approach (see: [PS Not](https://gking.harvard.edu/publications/why-Propensity-Scores-Should-Not-Be-Used-Formatching))

```
library(MatchIt)   # use for matching
library(tidyverse) # The overall package.  It will load lots of dependencies

set.seed(950)
n.size <- 1000

# This creates a tibble (an easier to use version of a data frame)
myData <- tibble(
a = lubridate::now() + runif(n.size) * 86400,
b = lubridate::today() + runif(n.size) * 30,
ID = 1:n.size,
#   d = runif(1000),
ivFactor = sample(c("Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3", "Level 4" ), n.size, replace = TRUE),
age = round(rnorm(n = n.size, mean = 52, sd = 10),2),
outContinuous = rnorm(n = n.size, mean = 100, sd = 10),
tmt = sample(c(1,0), size = n.size, prob = c(.3, .7), replace = TRUE)
)

# Using matching methods suggestions found in Ho, Imai, King and Stuart 
myData.balance <- matchit(tmt~age + ivFactor, data = myData, method = "nearest", distance = "logit")

# Check to see if the matching improved balance between treatment and control group
summary(myData.balance)

 # Extract the matched data.  Now we can use this in subsequent analyses
 myData.matched <- match.data(myData.balance)
```